# React and Redux: Wrapping React Map Function with a HTML tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my code below, I use React map function within a ternary operator. Code executes perfectly fine when I wrap the React map function with a div tag but if I remove the div tag, I get an error. Do we need to always wrap React map function with a tag like a div tag?

//React app

```
 render(){
      const { networkList, isLoading} = this.props.userNetwork;

      return(
        <React.Fragment>
        {isLoading === true ?
          <div className="ListUsers">
            <div className="Meta">
            <h3 className="NetworkListDefaultMessage">Loading...</h3>
            </div>
          </div>: networkList.count === 0?
          <div className="ListUsers">
            <div className="Meta">
            <h3 className="NetworkListDefaultMessage">No List</h3>
            </div>
          </div>:<div>
          **{networkList.network_list.map(person =>
              <div key={person.relationship_id} className="ListUsers">
                <div className="Meta">
                <h3 className="UserName">{person.name}</h3>
                </div>
              </div>)}**</div>
          }
        </React.Fragment>
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Fragment`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) component from React.
It allows you to group a bunch of elements into a single group without having to render an HTML tag. This is handy when you render `<li>` tags inside a `ul` tag as an example. But do note that you would not be able to render class names.

```
import { Fragment } from 'react';

// [...]

const { networkList, isLoading } = this.props.userNetwork;

return (
  <React.Fragment>
    {isLoading === true ? (
      <div className="ListUsers">
        <div className="Meta">
          <h3 className="NetworkListDefaultMessage">Loading...</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    ) : networkList.count === 0 ? (
      <div className="ListUsers">
        <div className="Meta">
          <h3 className="NetworkListDefaultMessage">No List</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    ) : (
      <div>
        {networkList.network_list.map((person) => (
          <Fragment key={person.relationship_id}>
            <div className="ListUsers">
              <div className="Meta">
                <h3 className="UserName">{person.name}</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Fragment>
        ))}
      </div>
    )}
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

A short hand for `<Fragment>` is `<>` which works just as well. But it may not be supported in all highlighters. Choose what you find works best for you.

Comment: Okay gotcha. If I want to render class names, I should use <div> tag instead of Fragment component?

Comment: Indeed. A `Fragment` will literally not render anything which means there is nothing to attach the class name to